# Accessing process instance variables from ProcessInstanceQuery

Tags: camunda

What is the proper way to query process instance variables in Camunda?

In Activiti there is a `getProcessVariables()` method available on the `org.activiti.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance` but it was removed from `org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

camunda introduced a new, separate query for process instance variables:

```
VariableInstance v = 
  runtimeService.createVariableInstanceQuery()
    .processInstanceIdIn(pId)
    .variableName("myVariable")
  .singleResult();
```